# pandas *efficiently* copy the valid value to other rows by groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

> "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil (but it's nice to have once you have an ugly solution)" D.Knuth

### Given this dataset

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv = StringIO("""country,year,surface,ground,tot_water,enviro,depend
Yemen,2012,2,1.5,2.1,0.55,0
Yemen,2013,,,,,
Yemen,2014,2,1.5,2.1,,0
Yemen,2015,,,,,
Yemen,2016,,,,,
Yemen,2017,,,,0.55,
Zambia,1995,,,,,
Zambia,1996,,,,,
Zambia,1997,104.8,47,104.8,31.48,23.47""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv)
df

Out[0]:
  country  year  surface  ground  tot_water  enviro  depend
0   Yemen  2012      2.0     1.5        2.1    0.55    0.00
1   Yemen  2013      NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN
2   Yemen  2014      2.0     1.5        2.1     NaN    0.00
3   Yemen  2015      NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN
4   Yemen  2016      NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN
5   Yemen  2017      NaN     NaN        NaN    0.55     NaN
6  Zambia  1995      NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN
7  Zambia  1996      NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN
8  Zambia  1997    104.8    47.0      104.8   31.48   23.47
```

I want to apply the valid values from `['surface', 'ground', 'tot_water', 'enviro']` columns and copy them to all of the countries. I have a solution but it could do with some optimising.

### Pseudo code:

1. Loop through each country and filter the dataframe to that subset
2. find the index for the first valid value of that column
3. set the value for that column equal to that valid value

### My solution

```py
vars_ = ['surface', 'ground', 'tot_water', 'enviro']
# for each country
for country in df.country.unique():
    # and each value in the
    filter_ = df.country == country
    for var in vars_:
        valid_ix = df[filter_][var].first_valid_index()
        df.loc[filter_, var] = df[var][valid_ix]

df

Out[]:
country  year  surface  ground  tot_water  enviro  depend
0   Yemen  2012      2.0     1.5        2.1    0.55    0.00
1   Yemen  2013      2.0     1.5        2.1    0.55     NaN
2   Yemen  2014      2.0     1.5        2.1    0.55    0.00
3   Yemen  2015      2.0     1.5        2.1    0.55     NaN
4   Yemen  2016      2.0     1.5        2.1    0.55     NaN
5   Yemen  2017      2.0     1.5        2.1    0.55     NaN
6  Zambia  1995    104.8    47.0      104.8   31.48     NaN
7  Zambia  1996    104.8    47.0      104.8   31.48     NaN
8  Zambia  1997    104.8    47.0      104.8   31.48   23.47
```

There has to be a more *efficient* way. On a medium sized dataset this takes quite a while and the for loops are unsightly. Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your logic is not very clear. Do you want to replace all the values by first True value or by country? Why are you overwriting values at index 8?

Comment: Good Spot! That shouldn't be happening it should be replacing teh values by country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the data by country and use bfill and ffill

```
df.groupby('country').bfill().ffill()

country     year    surface ground  tot_water   enviro  depend
0   Yemen   2012    2.0     1.5     2.1         0.55    0.00
1   Yemen   2013    2.0     1.5     2.1         0.55    0.00
2   Yemen   2014    2.0     1.5     2.1         0.55    0.00
3   Yemen   2015    2.0     1.5     2.1         0.55    0.00
4   Yemen   2016    2.0     1.5     2.1         0.55    0.00
5   Yemen   2017    2.0     1.5     2.1         0.55    0.00
6   Zambia  1995    104.8   47.0    104.8       31.48   23.47
7   Zambia  1996    104.8   47.0    104.8       31.48   23.47
8   Zambia  1997    104.8   47.0    104.8       31.48   23.47
```